Voltage references to keep load cell readings stable
My load cell readings (handled by my HX711) become unstable when I replug the USB cable (which is powering my ESP32-C3). And they become stable again if I reset the ESP32-C3.
Someone told me it was a voltage excitation issue and suggested I use a voltage reference.
I could only find the LM336 2
5 and TL431 2.5. Will those do?

Of course a voltage reference is a good thing. But, without additional info like schematic and layout, no one can tell you if the missing reference is really your problem. And no one can tell you if the LM336 has enough performance to meet your specific (?) requirements.

More likely you need some kind of noise filtering than anything a voltage reference could help with. Sticking ferrites on your power lines might help. Maybe a common-mode choke.

The HX711 has an internal regulator and the reading from a load cell (bridge) is ratiometric (typical +/-5ppm/°C gain drift) so it's very unlikely that tacking on some external reference will not make things considerably (like 10x) worse. Your problem is most likely elsewhere, like a software issue or some kind of wiring or electrical noise issue.
